# codeigniter image upload successful, but file not uploaded

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload

I have been trying to upload an image using CodeIgniter's File Upload class. The image is used for a user's avatar. Here is a snippet for my code:

```
//upload file
            if($_FILES['image']['name'] != ''){
                if (!file_exists($dirpath))
                    mkdir($dirpath);

                $this->load->library('upload');
                $config['upload_path'] = $dirpath;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|GIF|JPG|JPEG|PNG';
                $config['max_size'] = '0';
                $config['max_width'] = '0';
                $config['max_height'] = '0';
                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                $config['overwrite'] = true;
                $config['remove_spaces'] = false;

                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                $data = "";
                $error = "";

                $photo_result = $this->upload->do_upload('image');
                if ($photo_result)
                    if($action == 'update'){
                        foreach (glob($dirpath.'/'.$old_image.'*') as $file)
                            if (file_exists($file))unlink ($file);
                    }
                    if($new_resto->resized == 0){
                        if(resize_image($widths,$theuser))
                            $this->usermodel->update($theuser->id, array('resized'=>1), 'object',$authorization);
                    }
                echo json_encode(array('config'=>$config,'upload_data'=>$this->upload->data()));
                }
            }
```

The file upload is supposedly successful, because when I print out `$this->upload->data()`, it shows that the upload data is not empty. The strange thing is, this code works for creating new users, but when I try to update users, the file is not uploaded. I have tried using `chmod($dirpath, 0777)` before the upload, and `chmod($dirpath, 0755)` after, still no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake, I assigned `$old_image` after I updated the data, so `$old_image` contains the current  image name, causing it to be deleted when i call `unlink($file)`.

Problem solved :)

Comment: Interestingly enough, I just ran into the exact same mystery issue and it turned out to be a bug in my 'delete the old one' code. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Upload.php class with previous version of CodeIgniter